# Triggered Email on creation of a new case

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

I need to send a Marketing Cloud Triggered Email using Marketing cloud connect when a new case is created in Service Cloud. My email has some personalized information as well (e.g. CaseNumber).
I referred to the documentation and used the below AMPScript

My Triggered Email is failing. I think it is because I don't have the RecordID value of the Case

How can I get that?

```
%%[Set @mySObject = "Case" 
@myRecordId = RecordIdset 
@Case = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(@mySObject,"Subject,Status,Priority,CaseNumber","Id", "=", @myRecordId)
Set @CaseRow = Row(@Case, 1)
Set @Subject = FIELD(@CaseRow,"Subject")
Set @CaseNumber = FIELD(@CaseRow,"CaseNumber")]%%
```

Comment: Is this the actual definition of the record ID you're trying to set? `@myRecordId = RecordIdset`?

Comment: No it’s not and that’s exactly my confusion. How do I get the Case Record ID here?

Comment: Are you using Email Studio triggered send definition, or journey builder?

Comment: Triggered Send Definition in Email Studio